# Braintree Integration - User Credit Card Details only once

Tags: cordova, paypal, braintree

We are developing a cordova application which would be similar to Uber. 
Workflow is simple: User Requests for a service, an associate is assigned, after the work is completed, charge the user for number of hours.

I have the server generating the client token from braintree

```
    $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
```

and can ask the user to enter his credit card details only once for the first request, after which  I create a Braintree_customer object

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
                            'paymentMethodNonce' => $payment_token
                        ));
```

and store the token in my DB.

```
    $payment = new Payment;
    $payment->owner_id = $owner_id;
    $payment->customer_id = $customer_id;
    $payment->last_four = $last_four;
    $payment->card_token = $result->customer->creditCards[0]->token;
    $payment->save();
```

Can I use this customer id for all subsequent trasactions ?

```
Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
                            'amount' => $total,
                            'paymentMethodNonce' => $customer_id
                            ));
```

In this scenario, we would want the user to enter his card details only once and next time he creates another request even after a month or so, we should be able to bill him without he having to enter his card details.

Can I get a simple workflow as to how we can implement this and examples if any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'd want to use the **paymentMethodToken** key for the Transaction.sale, with that token string as the value, to charge a specific customer's stored payment method.

```
result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
    'amount' => $total,
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'token_string'
})
```

Therefore, for all subsequent transactions, you would want to use the paymentMethodToken and pass in that token string, as opposed to passing in the customer ID.

Comment: Hi what exactly is 'token_string' and where do I get it from asuming that I have a customer registered who already provided his credit card data and I don't want him to do it again?

Comment: @Maxlight this can be found in the [Braintree Customer result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/#payment_methods).  The [payment_methods](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/#payment_methods) attribute will return a list of the customer's stored payment methods.  Each payment method will contain the token string associated with it.

Comment: Thanks I see now :)

Comment: Btw I am using hosted fields for creditcard input and paypal payment, what should I do about them? Should I check if there is any stored payment method and if there are not show hosted fields or should they initialize differently if the returning customer with payment method exist?

Comment: Sounds like that's completely up to you, but I think it would be logical to find that customer in your Braintree Vault and check to see if they have any stored payment methods first.